# Как в scala корректно получить номер строки, метод/функцию, класс, пакет, etc...?

Tags: scala, playframework, runtime

Погуглил, но доминирует вариант java...

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber
```

но в `worksheet` возвращает всегда **5**, в рабочем проекте `scala/playframework 2.5` - всегда **35**

пробовал играться с `уровнем`, ничего осмысленного `не вышло`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался, для примера создаем `services/Log.scala`

```
package services

object Log {
  def info(text: String) = {
    val systemStr = makeSystemStr
    Console.out.println(Console.BLUE + "[INFO] " + systemStr + Console.RESET + text)
  }

  def makeSystemStr() = {
    val fileName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()(3).getFileName
    val lineNumber = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()(3).getLineNumber
    val cnArr = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()(3).getClassName.split("[$]")
    val pkgName = cnArr(0).split("[.]")(0)
    val name = cnArr(0).split("[.]")(1)
    val defName = cnArr(3)
    s"$pkgName : $fileName : $name : $defName : line $lineNumber - "        
  }
}
```

И можно использовать, например так

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import services.Log

class SomeCtrl extends Controller {
  def Index = Action { request =>
    Log.info("какой то текст лога")
    Ok("ok")
  }
}
```